# Nested Map loop async/await vs nested for loop async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express, asynchronous

I have a nested `map` loop with async awaits where I do 2 `promise.all` statements.
The data is formatted in 1 large array in which contains possibly multiple arrays of objects.
The inner loop will map through the objects in an array, and the outer loop will map through the arrays within the main array.

I'm using `map` since it is easy to keep this functioning with *parallel* performance versus *sequential*. I'm not sure if it is worth keeping it *parallel* or if there is a better way of doing this (maybe a *for-each* loop).

Here is the code (simplified/summarized) that I am using currently.

```
    const outerPromise = information.map(async order => {
    const innerPromise = order.moreInformation.map(async singleOrder => {
        if (something) {
            const response = await axios({ ... });
            return response.specificDataField;
        }
    });

    const orders = await Promise.all(innerPromise);
    return orders.filter((obj) => obj);
});

const orders = await Promise.all(outerPromise);

return orders;
```

Sorry if the formatting is slightly off, the indentation might be off, I couldn't get it to format properly.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
P.S. This is being written in JS/NodeJs (ExpressJs)

Edit:
I don't think the issue is with me filtering afterwards since it is the objects that would possibly come out null; I would need to filter after getting back the innerPromise (to see which are null?). 
That being said, it is really the 2 `map` statements that make me feel as if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: The "inner" `.map()` shouldn't be a `.map()`. And what do you mean with _" it is easy to keep this functioning with parallel performance versus sequential"_?

Comment: @Andreas why shouldn't it be a `.map()`? Sorry I meant _parallel_ performance is done by using `a map` and `Promise.all`, if I did a `for-each loop` it would've been a _sequential_ async/await. I could have all that confused if you have a better explanation for me that'd be awesome or a different approach maybe!

Comment: `.map()` returns a new value for every element of the array. Your "inner" `.map()` only returns something when the condition is fulfilled. Otherwise it would "return" `undefined`

Comment: @Andreas what would a better solution be? I realized that as well, I do a `filter()` afterwards but it doesn't seem so efficient; which is why I thought I'd ask here. I know `reduce()` doesn't do things in _parallel_. So i'm not so sure how i'd do this. Would it be better to have the `map()` for the outer-loop then a `for-each` for the inner-loop?

Comment: The other way round. First filter, then map.

Comment: @Andreas I _edited_ my comment but I just saw your recent one. That still won't solve my issue with having 2 maps for the simple fact that. If I filter first, I'm just filtering the array, not the objects in the array (which are the things that can possibly come back _null_). The outer `map()` is mapping each array inside the main array. The inner `map()` is mapping each object within an array. just like a nested-loop would.